# Fresh install Magento and can't login

Tags: admin, login

After the installation and I get to the main page of Magento the demo shows. The next thing I do is use the credentials I've provided during the installation. It will return **"The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later."** Now if I use my Admin URL that was created I get a page and no login box. Just saying Oops that page doesn't exist. (Soft 404).

What do I do next? I've reinstalled it several times.

I will note it is installed as an SSL cert page with a subdomain.

> --use-secure=1 
> --base-url-secure=https://store.mopar1973man.com/ 
> --use-secure-admin=1

Comment: Also figured out in the core_config_data there is no cookie information even in the database. web/cookie/cookie_domain is missing from the database. There is no cookie data or even an entry.

Comment: Found It. After going back to Tweak settings (in Cpanel) and disabled and re-enabled the file protection which reset all the folder permissions back to default the software started working.